# getting an additional ?> along with my json response

Tags: android

Hi i am making an application in which i am parsing the json response and i am getting an additional ?> along with my json response.I have tried everything.
Can anyone help please.I have pasted the code for reference .

```
package com.vitarkasolutions.tracker;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class test_class extends Activity{
    final static String url = "http://varun.esy.es/" ;
    String tag ="login";    
    String name="varundasas";
    String email="varunsdssdsdds@gmail.com";
    int lat= 10323422;
    int lang = 2055325;
    int phone_no= 532323;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);   
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            registerUser(name, email, tag, phone_no, lat, lang);    
        }
    });

    }


public void registerUser(String name, String email,String register_tag, int phone_no ,int lat , int lang )
{
    Log.d("tag errror", "hii");
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_no",String.valueOf(phone_no)));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",String.valueOf(lat) ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", String.valueOf(lang)));


            new parsingNew().execute(params);
                //AsyncTask parsing =new parsing().execute(params);


        }


public  class parsingNew extends AsyncTask<List<NameValuePair>, Void, Void> {   
    // Making HTTP request

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<NameValuePair>... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Log.e("tag", "parse function called");            
        try{
                // defaultHttpClient
         DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        Log.d("tag", "post");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params[0]));    
        Log.d("tag", "entity");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);                   
        Log.d("tag", "response");
        final int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
                { 
                    Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
                    Log.d("not Connected", "connected");
                }else{
                    Log.d("Connected", "connected");
                }
                Log.d("Con", "connected");
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();                                               
               InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();       
               Reader Reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                       is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               String line = null;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                   sb.append(line);
               }
               is.close();
            String   json = sb.toString();

                 Log.e("tag2", is.toString());         
                 Log.e("tag", json.toString());
                 Log.d("Reader", Reader.toString());
                 Gson gson = new Gson();                             
                 user user = gson.fromJson(Reader,user.class);   
                 Log.e("tag3", "done");
                 Log.e("tag4", user.toString());
                 Log.e("tag4", user.name);
                 Log.d("tag4", user.email);

        } 
        catch  (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

}       
}

}
```

Comment: a/ post the log. b/ did you consider this may come from the server?

Comment: Correction would be at php side. Not in java